# Mirroring Android screen on Chromecast

Tags: google-cast

Is it possible to mirror an Android device screen to a Chromecast device?
If so, can anyone refer me to some code samples?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I realize this is an old post, but ChromeCast mirrors with Android 4.2+ now.  Use the DisplayManager and Presentation APIs to detect the display and display different content onto the mirrored display.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible, but (currently) not without root. [Koush has just release a beta working on a Nexus 5](http://www.androidpolice.com/2014/03/05/koush-updates-mirror-with-super-beta-support-for-chromecast-screen-mirroring-currently-for-rooted-nexus-5-only/). Don't know if there's any source code available though.

Comment: Mirroring from a Chrome browser works fine , so I'm wondering what prevents the mirroring from an Android device...